# Puzzle Quest 2 skill arrangement for a Sorcerer through levels

Tags: xbox-360, nintendo-ds, puzzle-quest-2

How should I assign the skill points (strength, intelligence, etc) for my Sorcerer.

and what is a good progression, let say for each 10 levels:

- Start
- level 10
- level 20
- [...]
- level 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorcerer is Jack of all trades, so I keep him at 21 level across the board.

I would say there are 3 milestones in Sorcerer progression:

- Flameblade (lvl 7)
- Chasm (lvl 15)
- Mirror Shield (lvl 35)

At early levels (levels 10-15) surviving is the biggest challenge, at level 15 you can breathe much more freely and start attacking, and at level 35 you are laughing.

Before level 7 you would need mostly blue and yellow to keep ice shield going and have some defense. Once you learn Fireblade this probably would become you primary weapon so you would need to invest into red and purple skills. At level 15 you add Chasm to your arsenal that would require green skills. At level 35 Mirror Shield gives you pretty much ultimate protection so you can forget about yellow and blue skills and rather have more green and purple. And once you reach level 50 and want to toy with Mana Blast - it would require all skills to the max.

As you see Sorcerer needs pretty much all skills. It is safe to stop investing into yellow at about level 15 though and at blue a bit later. Other than yellow I would keep all skills more or less equal.

After level 20 or so you can rearrange your skills so your choice is not critical.

Also I posted some Sorcerer review [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2649/good-builds-for-character-in-puzzle-quest-2/2831#2831) if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, until level 16, I was investing almost everything in blue and purple, my blue stat was about 12 and got a +6 intelligence item. I was heavily depending of Ice Shield, and getting blue mana Was quite easy using Wild Mana and Hand of Ice . My main attack was from Mage Strike and I did not put Flameblade in my book so far since I was always high on blue. I will follow your advice and diversify for the next levels.